# Data Tables uploading to local PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running a data parser/web scraper with python. The parser then pushes the data (SQL Tables) to postgresql. However, I can't find the tables in pgadmin. This is part of a full stack django webapp, using docker, which I did not create but I am trying to get to run locally. As far as I can tell docker containers are working as intended, and so is the dataparsing script. Since I don't know much about issues like this please let me know if there is anything else I should include

Database connection in python

```
import psycopg2
import logging
import sys
import os


class DatabaseConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, user="postgres", password="1234", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", database="postgres",
                 course_table="course_info", prereqs_table="prereqs", antireqs_table="antireqs",
                 requirements_table="requirements", communications_table="communications",
                 breadth_table="breadth_table"):
        if os.getenv("UWPATH_ENVIRONMENT") is not None and os.getenv("UWPATH_ENVIRONMENT") == "docker":
            host = "db"
        if os.getenv("DB_PASS") is not None:
            password = os.getenv("DB_PASS")
        if os.getenv("DB_USER") is not None:
            user = os.getenv("DB_USER")
        if os.getenv("DB_NAME") is not None:
            database = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
        if os.getenv("DB_HOST") is not None:
            host = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
        if os.getenv("DB_PORT") is not None:
            port = os.getenv("DB_PORT")

        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.course_table = course_table
        self.prereqs_table = prereqs_table
        self.antireqs_table = antireqs_table
        self.requirements_table = requirements_table
        self.communications_table = communications_table
        self.breadth_table = breadth_table

        self.root = self.__Logger()


    def __Logger(self):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        if not len(self.logger.handlers):
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
            handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        return self.logger

    def execute(self, command):
        try:
            # self.root.info(command)
            print(command)
            self.cursor.execute(command)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(command)
            self.root.error(e)
            return False

    def commit(self):
        if self.connection:
            self.connection.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def select(self, what, table, condition=""):
        """
        SELECT <what> FROM <table> <condition>;

        :param what: string
        :param table: string
        :param condition: string
        :return: list
        """
        command = "SELECT " + what + " FROM " + table + " " + condition + ";"
        self.execute(command)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

[image: server connection settings in pgadmin]

Trying to access the backend in browser returns this, which makes me believes the tables don't exist in postgresql

[image]

[Output in txt file (roughly 300,000 lines, IDK if this is useful in analyzing the problem but thought I'd include it either way)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Okq2dBLexzLtNUadOkrgW45OIsUasq8/view)

Comment: can you not query any of these tables in pgadmin? or are they returning empty? any chance your parser wrapped all these sql statements into a transaction and did not commit?

Comment: @psychopg2 when running the datascraping file it creates a session in pgadmin. It creates a transaction start date but there is nothing in the transactions tab

Comment: okay. my guess is that you are running your data parser (it connects, it runs) but it is not committing the transaction. this would explain why the tables are not being created and you can't view them afterwards. without seeing more of the code from your data parser, this is hard for me to diagnose. psycopg2 doesn't automatically have auto-commit turned on which means you need set autocommit = True when you establish the connection or do "conn.commit()" before you close it.

Comment: How would I conn.commit() in terminal before exiting with ctrl-c? I can't input anything in

Comment: You can't. You're going to need to add it to your dataparsing script -- since this is likely where the issue lies.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Unfortunately it's already in there (I've updated the code snippet in the post) and the commit() function is called after before any dataframe is closed. I now believe that I just have an error in my postgres setup on my own device